# Spring Data JPA - Dynamic Table

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a structure for a table in a class file. Multiple tables will be created dynamically with same structure. Say, if u enter some text from client and click submit a table with that name will be created with existing structure and also we should be able to do CRUD operation on them. How to implement this in Spring Data JPA? Or is there any other solution for this in Java?

I have no idea of how to implement and I am beginner in spring boot since I am learning this for the past 2 weeks only.

Comment: I don't know of an end to end example of what you want, as it isn't common or overly a good idea - you've got a few special needs in there involving dynamic table creation and then mapping and validation of data going to that table. Do they really need separate tables? EclipseLink has a dynamic entity concept: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic and can be configured to create tables on the fly based on the dynamically created entities. It isn't straightforward in Spring though as it is using Native EclipseLink api